# React - Can't access props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I created a React Component which has a `canvas` and a `button`. When the component mounts, an event listener is added to the `button` to draw something over the canvas. Also, this event listener is removed once it is executed. This Component has a prop attribute `text`.

```js
<Canvas text="Hello"></Canvas>
```

On clicking the button, I get the following error. I'm unable to access the `text` prop.

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
```

Component -

```js
import React from "react";

class Canvas extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const button = this.refs.button;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    function action() {
      console.log("HI")
      ctx.font = "40px Consolas";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#F5F5F5";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText(this.props.text, 10, 40);
      button.removeEventListener("click", action);
    }
    
    button.addEventListener("click", action);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas ref="canvas" width={300} height={300} />
        <button ref="button" style={{
          display: "block",
          margin: "auto",
          marginTop: "10px"
        }}>Show</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Canvas;
```

Comment: `button.addEventListener`  No, this is not how you should be using React.

Comment: But to your error -> `this.props.text`   `this` will not be the `this` you think it is.  You will either want to put a closure other `this`, or bind the `action` function.

Comment: So `this` currently points to the `action` method?

Comment: No, it could be pointing to either `window` object, or `undefined` if in strict mode.  You could just put a closure other `this`,.  after the `ctx =...` line put, `const that = this`, and then inside the function put `that.props.text`..  or use `bind`, but I find closures much easier to reason with.

Comment: @Keith Understood. Thank you. One more question. What if I define `action` as an arrow function? Arrow functions don't have a `this` keyword of their own, right?

Comment: Yes, an arrow function will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#other_notes:

> When attaching a handler function to an element using addEventListener(), the value of this inside the handler will be a reference to the element. It will be the same as the value of the currentTarget property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

You should explicitly specify `this` when passing it.

Try this:

```
import React from "react";

class Canvas extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
   const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
   const button = this.refs.button;
   const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   function action() {
     console.log("HI")
     ctx.font = "40px Consolas";
     ctx.fillStyle = "#F5F5F5";
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
     ctx.fillText(this.props.text, 10, 40);
     button.removeEventListener("click", action);
   }
   const onButtonClicked = action.bind(this)

   button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClicked);
  }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <canvas ref="canvas" width={300} height={300} />
       <button ref="button" style={{
         display: "block",
         margin: "auto",
         marginTop: "10px"
       }}>Show</button>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
export default Canvas;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because you don't have access to context in the function. To avoid this, you can use `.bind(this)`. Can you explain, why you need to delete the event listener after the first use?
This is not something very common. My suggestion is to use `onClick={action}`.